# WPF: ListBox unselecting

Tags: wpf, select, listbox

1. When the user clicks on a item in my single-select `ListBox`, the item is selected.
2. When the user clicks on a item the second time, the item is not unselected unless they are holding the control key.

What is the recommended way to change #2 to not require the control key?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make sure the selection mode is `Multiple`. By selecting multiple:

> you can use the mouse to select and  deselect any item(s) you want with just a mouseclick. But if you want only 1 selected item at a time, you'll have to deselect the other items in code in the SelectionChanged event.

[Source](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wpf/thread/0b5e154b-26dd-4aa3-a16d-4c9659a16a49/)

```
Private Sub MainList_SelectionChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Controls.SelectionChangedEventArgs)
    If e.AddedItems.Count > 0 Then
        Dim valid = e.AddedItems(0)
        For Each item In New ArrayList(MainList.SelectedItems)
            If item IsNot valid Then MainList.SelectedItems.Remove(item)
        Next
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 4):

Sorry by resurrecting this topic...

But the accepted answer didn't cover well all my needs, so I improved it a little. I have dozens of `ListBox` and it all needs this *unselection on click* behavior.

Because of it, I created a custom control, overriding the `SelectionModeProperty` (setting its default value to `SelectionMode.Multiple`) and also tracking the `SelectionChanged` event automatically. Lets show the code:

```
public class UnselectableListBox : ListBox
{
    public UnselectableListBox() : base()
    {
        SelectionChanged += new SelectionChangedEventHandler((sender, e) =>
        {
            if (e.AddedItems.Count > 0)
            {
                var last = e.AddedItems[0];
                foreach (var item in new ArrayList(SelectedItems))
                    if (item != last) SelectedItems.Remove(item);
            }
        });
    }

    static UnselectableListBox()
    {
        SelectionModeProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(UnselectableListBox),
            new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(SelectionMode.Multiple));
    }
}
```

Then, I only need to replace my XAML with:

```
<local:UnselectableListBox ... />
```

No more need to code `SelectionChanged` for each `ListBox` on each `Window`.

Answer (score 1):

Not trying to beat a dead horse but I had this same problem and couldn't use any of the methods used in answers here... hope someone can benefit from my answer:

I have selection mode set to single.  I have double click events which makes multiple select mode not so desirable and hard to get double clicks to work.

`SelectionChanged` only fires if the selected item is different.  Easy way: Use `PreviewLeftMouseDownClick` and `PreviewLeftMouseUpClick`.  Store `MyListBox.SelectedIndex` into an object variable in the preview mouse down event.

In the preview mouse up event compare that variable from the down event to `MyListBox.SelectedIndex` and if they are the same set `MyListBox.SelectedIndex = -1`.

The item will be deselected if it is the same because the changing of index numbers happens after the preview down and before the preview up!

Answer (score 0):

Using the Control key *is* the recommended way to do this. It's a UI gesture which is consistent across all of Windows. You should be wary of changing this behavior.

Comment: Normally I would agree, but for my current design being able to easily unselect items is very important.

Comment: P.S. One of my concerns is that I want mouse-only control. If this gets placed on a touch screen, there will not be a keyboard available.

Answer (score 0):

I found that Ctrl-CLick is a non-intuitive way to unselect a listbox item and fixed the behavior by simply adding a MouseDown and KeyDown event in my XAML (.net Core 5) and creating event handlers like this:

```
private void lboxScanList_MouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e) {
    // user clicked on a non-item - deselect all
    lboxScanList.UnselectAll();
}

private void lboxScanList_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e) {
    if (e.Key == Key.Escape) {
        lboxScanList.UnselectAll();
    }
}
```

This gives you unselection with Esc or a mouse click off of any item but on the listbox which I feel is much more intuitive.