# Extend ListViewItem when selected

Tags: wpf, listview, triggers, listviewitem

I have this `ListViewItem` trigger:

```
<MultiDataTrigger>
    <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
        <Condition Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=IsMouseOver}" Value="True" />
        <Condition Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=IsSelected}" Value="True" />
    </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Gray"/>
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="White"/>
    <Setter Property="Height" Value="50"/>
</MultiDataTrigger>
```

When I am selecting my `ListViewItem`, this item becomes larger so I can show another elements.

Now I want to implement a behavior that after each click on a `ListViewItem` this item will change from selected to not selected, so after each click my `ListViewItem` changes its height to `50` and after another click back to `22` (the default size).

I subscribed to an `PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown` `event`:

```
private void listView_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{

}
```

My question is: what do I need to write into this event handler?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5144092/4862034 should work for listviews too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could handle the `PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown` event for the `ListViewItem` container:

```
<ListView x:Name="listView">
    <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
            <EventSetter Event="PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown" Handler="ListViewItem_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown" />
            <Style.Triggers>
                <MultiDataTrigger>
                    ...
                </MultiDataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
</ListView>
```

...something like this:

```
private void ListViewItem_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    ListViewItem lvi = (ListViewItem)sender;
    if (lvi.IsSelected)
    {
        listView.SelectedItems.Remove(lvi.DataContext);
        e.Handled = true;
    }
}
```

> I put this `EventSetter` after my `Style` (this style is in another file) and got this: 'ResourceDictionary' root element requires a `x:Class` attribute to support event handlers in the XAML file ...

If you define the `ItemContainerStyle` in a `ResourceDictionary`, you need to add a code-behind file to the `ResourceDictionary`. This is an easy thing to do:

[Is it possible to set code behind a resource dictionary in WPF for event handling?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/92100/is-it-possible-to-set-code-behind-a-resource-dictionary-in-wpf-for-event-handlin)

The other option would be to define the `Style` with the `EventSetter` inline in your view and base it on the `Style` with the `MultiDataTrigger` that you have defined in the `ResourceDictionary`:

```
<ListView x:Name="listView">
    <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ListViewItem" BasedOn="{StaticResource YourOtherStyleInTheResourceDictionary}">
            <EventSetter Event="PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown" Handler="ListViewItem_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown" />
        </Style>
    </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
</ListView>
```

Comment: I put this EventSetter after my Style (this style is in another file) and got this: 'ResourceDictionary' root element requires a x:Class attribute to support event handlers in the XAML file. Either remove the event handler for the PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown event, or add a x:Class attribute to the root element.

Comment: If you define the ItemContainerStyle in a ResourceDictionary you need to add a code-behind file to the ResourceDictionary: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/92100/is-it-possible-to-set-code-behind-a-resource-dictionary-in-wpf-for-event-handlin. Or you could just another ItemContainerStyle in your view and base this one on the one defined in the ResourceDictionary.

Comment: I sorry but i did not understand what to do, i have this ListViewItem.xaml file and inside App.xaml the declaration for this style file, so whay i should add ?

Comment: In your question, you said that you "subscribed to an PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown event". Where did you define this event handler?

Comment: In my ListView XAML

Comment: And what is that? A window? A UserControl?

Comment: simple ListView that i added in the main XAML

Comment: See my edit. Define the event handler in the code-behind of your "main XAML" and base the style in your "main XAML" on the one in your ResourceDictionary, i.e. replace "YourOtherStyleInTheResourceDictionary" with the x:Key of the Style in your ResourceDictionary.